# Don't be shy, give this puzzle a try

Tags: pattern, wordplay

What do the following words have in common, that 95% of other words do not have?

Girl
Walk
Inquire
Far
Live
Laugh
Inept
Break
Honest
Low

Comment: They're all english

Comment: @GintasK How do I even avoid those kinds of answers

Comment: It's not an answer :)

Comment: @Wu33o I would think that people would be able to infer that there were a unique property amongst this particular set of words (especially for such an intelligent community, who could come up with dozens of imaginative answers), but I have edited to state the blatantly obvious.

Comment: @Wu33o By this logic I could go through every riddle and just post 'something' as the answer.

Comment: @Wu33o I am just not sure what more I can say without it giving the answer away?

Comment: @Inazuma I don't know the answer, so I can't help you with that :) I'll delete my comments now, cause we're supposed to have these kind of discussions in chat but I don't have time for that now. Curious about the answer though!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They

> all have opposites (or at least kinda opposites) rhyming with "shy" and "try".

More specifically (there's one I'm not sure of):

Girl

> Guy

Walk

> Fly

Inquire

> Reply

Far

> Nigh

Live

> Die

Laugh

> Cry

Inept

> Fly, I think.

Break

> Tie (I wasn't altogether convinced by this but Inazuma has confirmed it)

Honest

> Lie (I don't like this much -- wrong part of speech -- but Inazuma has confirmed it's right)

Low

> High

Comment: All the one's you've gotten so far are correct, and your thinking is correct.

Comment: The only one wrong is 'inept', I was going for 'sly'.

Comment: Aha, OK. I think I like "fly" better, actually :-).

Comment: An alternative for "honest" is "sly", which is an adjective. Another for "far" is "nearby".

Comment: I like "sly" for honest better than I do for "inept". "Nearby" is pretty good but "nigh" is better because usually English rhyming goes from the last stressed syllable to the end, so "nearby" rhymes e.g. with "goodbye" but not exactly with "fly".

Comment: Agreed, "honest" should be "truth" or at least "honesty", but the syllable-match works out better for the prior.  I also dislike the idea of using the same word (differently defined) for two opposites. Disregarding the syllable-count issue and the part-of-speech issue, I think "exemplify" is better suited for "inept".

Answer (score 2):

I think they all have opposites

Girl

> Boy

Walk

> Run

Inquire

> Inform

Far

> Close

Live

> Die

Laugh

> Cry

Inept

> Competent

Break

> Fix

Honest

> Dishonest

Low

> High

Comment: Many words have opposites... but you are halfway there! You just need to be a little more specific.

Answer (score 0):

i think they all

> have vowels in them

Comment: So does this sentence, not the answer.

Comment: ha ha ha, thought so, it should not be that simple :)